# F# syntax of comma within lambda expression

Tags: lambda, syntax, f#

I'm new to F#. Can someone explain what the following lambda expression is saying? Specifically, what the comma after the `Some c.Id` is doing and what all the parenthesis are about?

```
(fun ((b, p), c) -> (b && p.SelectedInnerRow = Some c.Id, c))
```

I'm a bit confused coming from C#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parentheses are for deconstruction of tuples. The lambda expression takes a tuple of (a tuple and some value) and some other value; and it returns yet another tuple.

Now for the types involved - as the argument named `b` is operand to the boolean operator `&&`, it must be of type `bool`. The argument `p` has to have a property named `SelectedInnerRow`, which in turn ought to produce an option. This option is equality-compared to another option value of argument `c`'s property `Id`, so the whole expression will return a tuple of a bool and the unchanged argument `c`.)

```
(* Dummy types to make it work *)
type Foo = { SelectedInnerRow : int option }
type Bar = { Id : int }

(fun ((b, p), c) -> (b && p.SelectedInnerRow = Some c.Id, c))
(* val it : _arg1:(bool * Foo) * c:Bar -> bool * Bar *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I forgot that "=" in F# is a comparison operator, not an assignment. So the (..) around "b && p.SelectedInnerRow = Some c.Id, c" designates this as a tuple output?

Comment: Oh right, that right-hand side set of parenthesis is indeed not needed. The comma does signify instead that the expression will evaluate to a tuple.

Comment: @AlanWayne: Yes, (a, b) is a tuple in F#, defined by the comma. I.e. in some cases you can write a tuple without parentheses - try it in the REPL by writing "let a,b = 1,2". When starting out with F# I found the fact that in type declarations you use * between tupled elements, while in the code you use a comma, confusing.